# Erro ao conectar-se no banco de dados MySql usando aplicação C# no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, banco-de-dados, winforms

Olá, criei o form de cadastro e na hora que vou salvar os itens do text box no banco da o seguinte erro 'Host 'DESKTOP_R70LLO is not allowed to connect to this MySql server'. 
Pela minha atidude de procurar resolver o erro e com base no que eu ja sei, creio que o usuario utilizado na conexão nao esta tendo a permissão para se conectar. Ou seja este usuaio = root, localhost, pass= 123 que coloquei no appconfig não tem permissao pra conectar. Mas a permissao de DELETE, INSERT e etc ta normal.

Comment: Você já tentou simular a conexão com o banco de dados com um Front End (WorkBench) por exemplo?

Comment: Sim, estou rodando em um localhost mas ele simula a conexao como se fosse remota.

Comment: Posta o teu appconfig pra eu dar uma olhada

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConexaoBD" value="server=localhost; uid=root; password=galaxy; database=sistema_venda"/>
  </appSettings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>

Comment: No teu visual studio tá instalado o plugin do mysql pro visual studio?

Comment: Esta sim, ja desinstalei e instalei novamente mais nao funcionou

Comment: Você consegue estabelecer uma conexão no menu do visual studio(2017) > Ferramentas > conectar-se a um banco de dados?

Comment: eu uso o enterprise 2015, pois tenho outro projeto com conxão no mesmo banco e funciona normal. Ja fis um form pra testar a conexao retornando o status da conexao. E vai normal. Mais esse não vai ja fis de tudo. Tenho que dar continuidade no projeto mais isso ta me travando, nao sei mais oq eu faço

Comment: @GleysonSilva eu fiz uma conexao direta em Ferramentas > Conectar-se a um BD. E Conectou normal.

Comment: Então em cada projeto você tem um AppConfig?

Comment: Já comparou os dois pra ver se tem algo diferente entre eles?

Comment: Sim em cada projeto tem AppConfig, e a dos dois projetos estao identicos.

Comment: A unica coisa que muda e o nome do schema (Database)

Comment: Gleyson voce quer um zip dos projetos no email? Claro se nao for encomodo, e se não liga em me ajudar. Ai voce pode ver como esta!

Comment: manda pra gleyson@intelider.com.br.

Comment: Ok, obrigado...

Comment: Ola Gleyson, eu troquei de banco ja que estou meio sem tempo de corrigir esse erro. Estou usando SQL server, mas todavia se voce conseguir encontrar o erro e me falar eu agradeço.

Comment: tentei muitas coisas mas nenhuma funcionou, cheguei até a criar um até um projeto novo mas não funcionou, como faz muitos anos que não mexo com windows forms isso atrapalhou. Mas vou continuar tentando aqui, assim que tiver uma resposta eu posto e te aviso.

Comment: Tudo bem ok, obrigado pela atenção e ajuda.

Comment: @nantanfoleto blz amigo, realmente também não consegui, deve ter alguma explicação, porém não encontrei nada nos arquivos.

Comment: Ok Gleison, pode deixar quieto, ja procurei outra forma de trabalhar com o banco, vamos desativar essa questão e mais uma vez obrigado pela sua atenção em me ajudar.